Proving that if the equation has two equal roots then $p^2 =4q: (1-q+p^2/2)x^2 +p(1+q)x +q(q-1)+p^2/2 = 0$
Question: Suppose $p$ and $q$ are real number which do not take simultaneously the values $p=0,q=1$. Suppose the equation
$$\left(1-q+\dfrac{p^2}2\right)x^2+p(1+q)x+q(q-1)+\dfrac{p^2}2=0$$
has two equal roots. Prove that $p^2 = 4q$
This is what I have done: I know that for the equation to have real coincident roots $D=0$
(here D is the Discriminant)
$D= b^2 -4ac$
here, $b= p+pq \implies b^2 = p^2+2p^2q+p^2q^2$
and
$-4ac= -1(2-2q+p^2)(2q^2-2q+p^2)=-1(4q^2 -4q+2p^2-4q^3+4q^2-2p^2q+2p^2q^2-2p^2q+p^4)$
Since 2 and 2 would have multiplied up to 4 in the denominator i cancelled it out
$\implies D=p^2+2p^2q+p^2q^2-1(4q^2 -4q+2p^2-4q^3+4q^2-2p^2q+2p^2q^2-2p^2q+p^4)=0 $
$\implies D=p^2+2p^2q+p^2q^2-4q^2+4q-2p^2+4q^3-4q^2+2p^2q-2p^2q^2+2p^2q-p^4=0$
Now on combining like terms i have:
$D=(p^2-2p^2)+(2p^2q+2p^2q+2p^2q)+(p^2q^2-2p^2q^2)+(-4q^2-4q^2)+4q+4q^3-p^4=0$
$\implies D= -p^2+6p^2q-p^2q^2-8q^2+4q+4q^3-p^4=0$
$\implies p^2=6p^2q-p^2q^2-8q^2+4q+4q^3-p^4$
I am unable to simplify this further to obtain $p^2=4q$ although when putting $4q$ instead of $p^2$ the equation's LHS is equal to RHS

You are almost there.
You just have to realize that
$D=0\Leftrightarrow p^2-6p^2q+p^2q^2+8q^2 -4q-4q^3+p^4=0$
can be rewritten as
$(p^2-4q)\cdot( p^2+(q-1)^2)=0$
and the second factor never vanishes because $(p, q)\neq(0, 1)$.
